# Swift 2.2 Iterable Stack Data Structure

Tags: swift2, stack

I have a need for a Stack data structure in Swift 2.2 that is:

- Generic
- Has the traditional functionality:

  - push()
  - peek()
  - pop()
- In addition has the following functionality:

  - Indexable
  - Iterable

The following code used to work, but now that I've upgraded to Swift 2.2, the code doesn't compile.  The error message is that Stack doesn't conform to the SequenceType protocol.  I suspect that something new has been added to the protocol, that is required now that wasn't required to be implemented before.

```
//
//  Stack.swift
//
//  Created by kaydell on 7/30/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015-2016 Kaydell Leavitt. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

public class Stack<T>: SequenceType {

    private var values: [T] = []

    public var count: Int {
        return values.count
    }

    public subscript(i: Int) -> T {
        return values[i]
    }

    public func push(t: T) {
        values.append(t)
    }

    public func peek() -> T? {
        let lastIndex = values.count - 1
        if lastIndex <= -1 {
            return nil
        } else {
            let t = values[lastIndex]
            return t
        }
    }

    public func pop() -> T? {
        let lastIndex = values.count - 1
        if lastIndex <= -1 {
            return nil
        } else {
            let t = values.removeLast()
            return t
        }
    }

}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I need to implement from the SequenceType protocol, to make my code compile.

I like Eclipse, when programming in Java.  If a Java interface requires methods to be implemented Eclipse tells you which methods needs to be implemented and will even write stubs for those methods for you, upon request.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1

Does Swift 2.2 have an API for a Stack data type? Or, can somebody help me fix my code so that it works again?

Answer (score 2):

Swift keeps changing so quickly. If you write Swift 2 code today, it's gonna be obsolete in a few months when Swift 3 comes out. Anyhow, here's how you can do it in Swift 2.

```
public class Stack<T>: SequenceType {
    public typealias Generator = StackGenerator<T>

    public func generate() -> Stack.Generator {
        return StackGenerator(stack: self)
    }

    // your push(), pop(), peek(), etc...
}

public class StackGenerator<T>: GeneratorType {
    public typealias Element = T

    let stack: Stack<T>
    var index: Int

    init(stack: Stack<T>) {
        self.stack = stack
        self.index = stack.count
    }

    public func next() -> StackGenerator.Element? {
        guard index > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        index -= 1
        return self.stack[index]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let stack = Stack<Int>()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)

for value in stack {
    print(value)
}
```

Let's just hope that the code converter can automagically upgrade it to Swift 3 when that one comes out.